# PHP/SQL select all with join when two tables have the same ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm just getting the hang of JOINs in SQL (very powerful, could have made my code a lot more efficient if I'd looked them up earlier!), but am struggling with joining two or more tables with the same column name, then processing with PHP.

Here's the query that I've been trying, using aliases

```
SELECT *, TABLE1.ID AS t1_id, TABLE3.ID AS t3_id
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3

etc (with a left join)
```

Only `table1` and `table3` have the same ID column name, is there something wrong in this code?  I'm getting the dreaded  `mysqli_error()` in PHP!

Any help greatly appreciated - can't seem to find the solution elsewhere when selecting everything from more than one table.  Could specify each column name, but there would be over one hundred!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t1.ID AS t1_id,
  t2.ID AS t2_id, 
  t3.ID AS t3_id
FROM
  TABLE1 as t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 AS t3
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Jade Could definitely do this but there are over 100 fields to specify in total, but only 2 have the same column name!  Do you know if there is a way to combine this with a select all from a table?

Comment: Yes you can still do a SELECT * as long as each table has it's own alias -- each ID will get an alias as well

Comment: I'm sure you can add t1.*, t2.*, t3.* etc. to the above. Won't that give you all the columns you need?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  I've now got it working with specific table names, although I'm still struggling with selecting everything.  Here's my query now with my real table names, which returns an error
'SELECT *
FROM
  ASSOCIATES_APPLICATIONS as aa,
  LIST_OF_EMPLOYERS as loe
LEFT JOIN LIST_OF_EMPLOYERS as loe
 ON aa.PARTNER_EMPLOYER = loe.ID'

Comment: Your SQL syntax is wrong. It should be: SELECT * FROM ASSOCIATES_APPLICATIONS as aa LEFT JOIN LIST_OF_EMPLOYERS as loe ON aa.PARTNER_EMPLOYER = loe.ID

Comment: Thanks @Jade, with your help I was able to work out exactly what I wanted - only the duplicate column names need to be specified with aliases.  I have edited the original answer above.